# How do I detect if my other apps were bought by the user?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

We have some small similar apps in appstore with small portion of content in each, every app is paid.
Now we made large app with in-apps and all content from previous apps + new features and some new content. App is free. 
Users are asking for getting content from previos apps for free and it's honest - some of them already paid for it

Update:
To be a little more specific - I need to choose between 3 ways:

1. Updating small apps (like said in the first answer) to use
   keychain
2. Updaiting small apps to send sone unique codes to our
   server (or other custom way of detecting)
3. Find a way to it
   without updating small apps (a lot of them!)

Comment: You need to update every small apps to use keychain to store informations and share this keychain with the large app

Comment: Any tips where to start with keychain usage?

Comment: This will not work if the user has bought the app but doesn't have it currently installed on the device. Am I wrong ?

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html but maybe @sch is right, if the app is bought but not installed i don't think that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169381/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-has-an-ios-app-installed). Shows how to check if a user has a specific app using the `canOpenURL` Method.

Simplest way in my book.

Comment: One more question - should app named be registered for opening as URL?   Now I have no success using "com.companyName.appName://" as URL string.