# Is it possible to check if a particular app is installed on a device?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a user has an iOS app installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169381/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-has-an-ios-app-installed)

Is it possible to check if, for example the Twitter or Pinterset or any app is installed on an iOS device from within your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly possible using the SDK. If an application you're looking for registers a URL scheme that it can open, then you can check for the presence of that app using the UIApplication -canOpenURL: method, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).