# How to determine if an iOS user has an app installed already?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

LinkedIn's mobile website seems to know if users have installed their app, regardless of whether they're logged in.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169381/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-has-an-ios-app-installed) addresses how to determine if a user has an iOS app, but this requires Objective-C.

How can you replicate the LinkedIn functionality, and determine from a website, whether users have installed a specific app?

Is LinkedIn just relying on a sophisticated cookie system? If so, how do they tie the cookie to a unique device and app installation?

We assume there isn't some new programmatic way of querying an iOS device for a list of installed apps?

Comment: Perhaps this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200) could shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this page provides the answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html