# How do you know if you have the Steam App installed on your phone

Tags: ios, swift

The STEAM app does not have URL_scheme，
Apple's proprietary API checks don't work either
I am looking forward to your reply ，thank you

Comment: If it doesn't have a URL scheme then you can't know if is installed.  Even if it did have a URL scheme, you can't really know if is installed.  All you know is that there is some app that declares that URL scheme

Comment: That said, I can't tell if the Steam app is installed on the phone? Do you have any way to detect if Steam App is installed on my phone？Thank you for your reply.

Comment: As I said, no.  Due to sandboxing an app can't really know about what other apps are on the phone.  You can use `canOpenUrl` to see if there is an app registered for a particular urlscheme.  That's it

Comment: You might like to check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169381/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-has-an-ios-app-installed